# iOS: How to avoid special characters being entered in a search bar?

Tags: ios, search, full-text-search

I may be looking at this incorrectly, but right now, if a user enters certain special characters in a search bar, the app will crash. These include \ and '.

The apostrophe is a problem, in that words like "isn't"  and "doesn't" will cause a crash

How should I go about working around this problem?

Many thanks

Comment: Rather than just preventing users from entering those characters, why don't you approach the problem from the angle of fixing whatever causes the crash when those characters are entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing a search using the search string, pre-filter it, like this:

```
NSString *safeSearchString = [[searchString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: Nick,  I've tried this code as follows: NSString *testString = tableModel.searchBar.text;
 testString = [[NSCharacterSet componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""]; but I get an error - no known class method.. Could you please elaborate.. I see this, combined with other answers as a way to allow people to type whatever they please. Thanks!

Comment: I missed a second ] after invertedSet] - I've updated my answer, try it now.

Comment: Also, your code is wrong - it's not testString = [NSCharacterSet componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:...], it should be testString = [testString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:...]

Comment: Thanks Nick. That works, so I'll mark complete. It's too bad I can't mark everyone as helpful on this one.. I will incorporate bits of everyone's answer..

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you escape the characters and actually search for what the user wants instead of ignoring or removing what they want ?

Are you using SQLite ? If so then you can escape a single quote by another single quote.

Comment: I'm using a sqlite store within core data. I like your approach (I presume it's similar to Jaserian's above).

Answer (score 1):

The UISearchBar utilizes the [UISearchBarDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.  To stop users entering \ and ' all you need to do is to override the `searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` method and if you sense the special characters in the text, you simply return `NO`.

But handling (rather than ignoring) these special chars in your program is a better user experience.  After all why are you users even searching for "isn't" and "doesn't" in the first place?

Comment: Hi Peter, the search bar will be for full-text searches and these could include those words.